# Bulk link checker in php

Tags: php, curl

I want to check the links in my database, if the status of the link (through possible redirections) is still valid (e.g. status 200). The below script is what I currently use. The limitation is that over +/- 400 links, the server gives me a 500 - internal error. Unfortunality, I cannot review the servers logs on what the reason is, my assumption is that it's a time out issue.

How can I make this script scalable, so that it will allow me to run more then the currently +/- 400 links?

```
function urlValidator($url) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($httpcode != '200') {
        echo $url;
        echo " - ". $httpcode;
    }
}

// creation of $url_array
//

foreach($url_array as $url){

    if(!is_null($url)) {
        urlValidator($url);
    }
}
```

I did try to add flush() and/or ob_flush() to the code, but it didn't help either (or implemented wrongly).

Any suggestions are more then welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default execution time of a PHP script is 30 seconds. After that it will time out.

You can either increase this time to something like this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //10 minutes
```

**But**, to make it really scalable, I would store the current "link-check" status in a database, so that you can continue where you left off and have multiple instances call your script.

Comment: For the multiple instances, you would breakup the job in sections of say 50 links, update the DB and then rerun the script? Would you see that as calling the same script every 30 seconds using cronjob, looking for the next 50 links without an update?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant. You just have to make sure you aren't checking the same links multiple times ;)